# Updating the id column's Identity Specification on an active table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a live (meaning it's used by my users) Table with a column "some_id" that was never set to be "Is Identity" when the table was created. I now have 2000 rows where some_id is NULL.

Can I Change the Identity Specification now and is it possible something would break for my users ?

Should I first update every Row's "some_id" with a prepared statement so that the first entry's some_id would be 1, the second would be 2, etc and then set it to Identity ? (I do have a unique date column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not alter an existing column and add `identity()`, but you could drop the existing column and add a new column with `identity()`., and it will automatically populate.

```
alter table t drop column some_id;
alter table t add some_id int not null identity(1,1);
```